# str replace removing all commas

Tags: php, string, str-replace, codeigniter-3

So I have a pretty simple problem here.

When I run a str_replace function on a comma separated list to remove a value with a comma infront of it, the function removes ALL of the commas in the list.

What am I doing wrong here?

The objects in question:

$tags = "16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22"

$tag_id = "17"

The code:

```
if (strpos($tags, ', '.$tag_id))
{
 //remove this in this format
  $new_tags = str_replace(', '.$tag_id, "", $tags);
}
elseif (strpos($tags, $tag_id.', '))
{
  //remove this in this format
  $new_tags = str_replace($tag_id.', ', "", $tags);
}
else
{
  //just remove the number
  $new_tags = str_replace($tag_id, "", $tags);
}
```

Comment: thats the purpose of `str_replace`. to replace ALL instances of what you want to replace in the string.

Comment: but  the tag_id is unique. Or does that not really matter here?

Comment: What is your expected output post it over here too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're actually looking for is:

```
$tags = (...);
$tag_id = 17;
$tags_array = explode(',', $tags);
if(($idx = array_search($tag_id , $tags_array )) !== false) {
    unset($tags_array[$idx]);
}
$tags_cleaned = implode(', ', $tags_array);
//16, 18, 20, 21, 22
```

[Functional example](https://eval.in/395268)

Answer (score 0):

Is your $tag_id correctly initialized before doing the str_replace ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's easier to handle this csv list operations in an array. Using explode and some array operations helping you doing that.

```
$list = array_map('trim', explode(',', $tags));
$flippedList = array_flip($list);
unset($flippedList[$tagId]);

$newTags = join(',', array_flip($flippedList));
```